# Add back arrow to pre-built FirebaseUI Sign-in?

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Action bar back arrow is available elsewhere in my app and for consistency I'd like it in pre-built Firebase sign-in activity too.

[image]

Here's my code without anything special in manifest.

```
void firebaseSignIn() {
    // Choose authentication providers
    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build());

    // Create and launch sign-in intent
    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)       
                    .build(),
            REQUEST_CODE_FIREBASE_SIGN_IN);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a built-in feature of FirebaseUI. If you want it, you will have to modify the code yourself. Since FirebaseUI is an open-source project, I'm quite sure they'd appreciate a Pull Request with the updates in that case.

Alternatively, you can file a feature request on the repo, and see if/wait until somebody is willing to implement it for you.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I'll give it a shot.